# How to count the number of times a word appears in an array

Tags: java, arrays, count

I am trying to count the number of times each word is in the array in java and then display it, but I can't figure out how I am using a scanner to add to the array and then trying to find a method that will go through the array and show how many times each word is in that array.

```
public class Counting {

    static String[] words = new String[3];
    //static int[] aCounts;
    private static int count;

    public static void countTimesWordApperesInArray() {
        int size = words.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            int position = i;
            int count = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                String element = words[i];
                if (words[i].contains(element)) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(words[i] + " " + count);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter three Words");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        String input = scanner.next();

        while (!("-1").equals(input)) {
            words[count] = input;
            count++;
            input = scanner.next();
        }
        //print();
        countDigits();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you're experiencing? Error message? Wrong behavior? Is the call to `countDigits` supposed to be calling `countTimesWordApperesInArray()`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

change `words[i].contains(element)` to `words[j].equals(element)`

```
public static void countTimesWordApperesInArray() {
        int size = words.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i += 1) {
            int count = 0;

            String element = words[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j += 1) {
                if (words[j].equals(element)) {
                    count += 1;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(words[i] + " " + count);
        }
    }
```